# Android TextView fontFamily not working when set via TextAppearance

Tags: android, fonts

I am having issues when using android:fontFamily when set via TextAppearance styles.

- Setting global font through android:fontFamily in theme works
- Setting android:fontFamily directly on TextViews works (I am using AppCompat and it correctly inflates the AppCompatTextView during inflation from xml, so no issues here)
- When setting the font via styles, it just does not work. Any help will be much appreciated. I am thinking that this has to do with how AppCompatTextView processes the style attributes, but have not had much luck in finding the exact root cause.

```
    <style name="TextAppearance.Header">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/headerfont</item>
    </style>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Header" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...hope it will work.

```
    <style name="TextAppearance.Header">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/headerfont</item>
    </style>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.Header" />
```

Comment: This worked! Just trying to figure out why. Could this be an issue with the support library?

Comment: Here you are trying to set value of one attribute to another. That's not possible. You have to set as style. You can't set font family value to text appearance. If you find my answer is helpful then please accept it and give an upvote.